# Какой файл указать в CREDENTIALS_FILE

Tags: python, heroku

Делаю бота в телеграм и дело дошло до деплоя на Хероку. Но я в своем боте задействовал библиотеку гугл для управления google sheets.

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import os
import json


def send_values_to_table(table_name, operation, score, link="", amount=""):
    CREDENTIALS_FILE = (".profile")
    spreadsheet_id = os.environ.get("spreadsheet_id")

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        CREDENTIALS_FILE,
        ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"])
    httpAuth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build("sheets", "v4", http = httpAuth)
```

Строка `spreadsheet_id = os.environ.get("spreadsheet_id")` принимает значение из Config Vars Heroku.

Но вот в `CREDENTIALS_FILE = (".profile")` проблема, я не знаю что сюда указывать.
делал я все по этому гайду: https://medium.com/@mandarvaze/how-to-safely-use-google-application-credentials-on-heroku-4e310ad67934

У меня на Heroku сейчас вот так: [image: heroku screenshot]

Подскажите, что ввести в CREDENTIALS_FILE чтоб все заработало

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все было легче, чем вообще нужно было

Нужна лишь одна запись в Heroku, содержание всех ключей google sheets

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нам нужно получить эти данные с Heroku: `CREDENTIALS = os.environ["GOOGLE_CREDITIONALS"]`
Далее нужно использовать метод `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict` который похож на `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name`, но вместо файла принимает `dict`.

Нужно преобразовать `CREDENTIALS` в `dict`: `json.loads(CREDENTIALS)` и у меня получился такой код:

```
CREDENTIALS = os.environ["GOOGLE_CREDITIONALS"]
spreadsheet_id = os.environ.get("spreadsheet_id")
    
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
    json.loads(CREDENTIALS),
    ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
)
httpAuth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build("sheets", "v4", http = httpAuth)
```

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)